# Remove a backslash character from a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I want to remove a backslash  character from this string:

```
String result = "[{\"venues\":{\"venueId\":1,\"name\":\"First Venue\","
            + "\"telephone\":\"jkljl\",\"description\":\"Edited Description\","
            + "\"address\":\"jlkjlj\",\"city\":\"lkjl\",\"postcode\":\"M221TX\","
            + "\"image\":z\"abcImage007.jpg\",\"latitude\":53.37655,\"longitude\":-2.27418,\"deleted\":0,"
            + "\"events\":[{\"eventId\":3,\"name\":\"Test Event\",\"description\":\"Test Event Description\",\"date\":\"24/07/2011\",\"startTime\":\"11:11\",\"venueId\":0,\"deleted\":1},"
            + "{\"eventId\":3,\"name\":\"Test Event\",\"description\":\"Test Event Description\",\"date\":\"25/07/2011\",\"startTime\":\"11:11\",\"venueId\":0,\"deleted\":1}]}}]";
```

I have tried:

```
String abc = result.Replace(@"\",@"");
String abc = result.Replace(@"\",string.Empty);
String abc = result.Replace(@"\\",@"");
String abc = result.Replace(@"\\",string.Empty);
```

But nothing is working. Could someone help please.

Thanks

Comment: String abc = result.Replace("\\",""); ?

Comment: this is string hasn't '\' character, but "\"" == ".

Comment: Your string contains an escape character for quotation marks, not backslashes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your string doesn't contain `\`

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit, you string contains embedded quote characters which is achieved by escaping the " character with a \.  if you print out the "result" variable you will not find a \ in it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to remove them. \" is escape sequence that shows that in your string is " symbol(quotation mark)

Answer (score 1):

More fully:

Your string doesn't contain the \ character. In the variable declaration it is used to escape the " character so that it can be put into the string without causing the end of the string to occur.

If write out the value of the variable somewhere you'll find there are no \ characters

Answer (score -1):

test this code

```
String abc = result[0].Replace(@"\",@"");
String abc = result[0].Replace(@"\",string.Empty);
String abc = result[0].Replace(@"\\",@"");
String abc = result[0].Replace(@"\\",string.Empty).
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)